# UIAlertAction handler called at the wrong time?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have a function that looks like this:

```
@IBAction func showAlert(){

//Some irrelevant code

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close this alert", style: .default, handler: {
    action in
        self.startNewRound()
    })


alert.addAction(action)

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Here is `updateLabels()`:

```
updateLabels() { 
targetLabel.text = String(targetValue)
scoreLabel.text = String(score)
roundLabel.text = String(round)
```

Here are some global variables:

```
var currentValue: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!
var targetValue: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roundLabel: UILabel!
var round: Int = 0
```

Here is startNewRound():

```
func startNewRound() {
targetValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(100)) + 1
currentValue = 50
slider.value = Float(currentValue)
round += 1
updateLabels()
}
```

The idea is that this function is called whenever a certain button in my main view controller is pressed, and then an alert pops up. Once the user closes the alert, `startNewRound()` is called.

However, with this current code, `startNewRound()` is only called once the user presses the view controller button again, after the user has already closed the alert. How do I get `startNewRound()` to run immediately after the alert is closed?

Comment: What does `startNewRound` do?  Have you set breakpoints to see what your code is doing when the user taps the alert button?

Comment: I am surprised this even compiles. How do you add an `UIAlertAction` to another `UIAlertAction`.

Comment: `startNewRound` starts a new round in the game that this code is for; it resets some numbers and some labels.

Comment: `startNewRound` called twice after `UIAlertController` dismiss then, check your view lifecycle methods, `viewwillappear`  `viewdidappear`, i think you calling `startNewRound` in these method also.

Comment: I'm calling `startNewRound()` once in `viewDidLoad()` when the app starts and once in `showAlert()` as you can see in the code I posted. I don't even have any functions called `viewwillappear` or `viewdidappear`.

Comment: I've also discovered that pressing any other button, after I've closed the alert, results in `startNewRound` being called; perhaps the `UIAlertAction`'s `handler` is dependent on other buttons being pressed first?

Comment: Your problem description sounds very much like a thread issue, i.e. UI code being called from a background thread... but your alert handler is guaranteed to be called from the main thread. So my guess is that inside `startNewRound` you do some UI manipulation in a background thread, and only see the effects of which when a user interaction (the next button press) causes the run loop to trigger. Long story short: please post the code of `startNewRound` as well :)

Comment: is showAlert() call from tableview??

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
@IBAction func showAlert(){

    //Some irrelevant code

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close this alert", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
            self.startNewRound()
    }

    alertController.addAction(closeAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: No change, issue still persists.